# How to debug errors in Sailsjs Controllers as with "error: A hook (`controllers`) failed to load!"

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

The following is an error I receive if I merely have a minor typo any one of my controllers. Only when I know what controllers I have lasted worked on and what code has been recently updated do I have enough information to make debugging a reasonable process. How do I debug such that when a controller fails to validate in Sailsjs I am given a better clue as to where the problem is?

```
Debugger listening on port 51121
error: A hook (`controllers`) failed to load!
error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at /Users/KMT/Documents/Personal/chat-sails-angular2/node_modules/include-all/index.js:129:29
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at requireAll (/Users/KMT/Documents/Personal/chat-sails-angular2/node_modules/include-all/index.js:44:9)
    at /Users/KMT/Documents/Personal/chat-sails-angular2/node_modules/include-all/index.js:54:23
    at Array.forEach (native)
```

`SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` should include some context - possibly the validated class, or filename.

Answer (score 1):

That is not easy and I found the same issue with my project at some point.
Call me crazy, but I just tried to take out of the folder one by one in order which I changed more recently and after 2 iterations I found which controller is giving this strange issue.